# ErrorPageFilter changes error codes to HTTP 200 OK

Tags: spring-boot

It seems like Spring Boot's ErrorPageFilter changes all my HTTP status codes to 200 OK (apart from 4xx). This only occurs when deploying to a Servlet container. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

To reproduce this I created a really simple Spring Boot app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ResponseErrorController extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResponseErrorController.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(ResponseErrorController.class);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/304")
    public void lala(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.sendError(304, "Not Modified");
    }
}
```

When launching this with **non-embedded**  Tomcat (or Jetty) opening http://localhost:8080/304 in the browser I always get a 200 OK (without content).

After some debugging I found that the ErrorPageFilter does not delegate the status code from the wrapped response to the real one. I know that I can return ResponeEntity in my controller but my actual problem occurs with a Servlet of another framework that sends the 304 - this controller is only to demo.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: 304 is not an error so the container probably ignores it. Try `response.setStatus()`.

Comment: We are using Tapestry and I've seen that they fixed this issue with 5.3  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAP5-1950

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status codes below 400 are no errors and should be set via `setStatus(int)` instead of `sendError(int)`. `ErrorPageFilter` therefore only handles sendError calls with status code >= 400.

So here's how to fix it:

- If it's your own code: use `setStatus(int)` instead.
- If a third-party servlet or filter sends 3xx status codes via `sendError(int)`: as a workaround you can remove or replace the `ErrorPageFilter` in your `SpringBootServletInitializer` via:

  ```
  protected WebApplicationContext run(SpringApplication application) {
      application.getSources().remove(ErrorPageFilter.class);
      return super.run(application);
  }
  ```